# Subscribe API call data is coming slowly in the ngOnInit()

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular 8, Subscribe API call data is coming slowly in the ngOnInit() and pass that data as @Input to one component modules to another component modules that is coming as undefined, After 1 mintues time span only it is coming with data. Please tell how resolve the issue.

State-change.html

```
<app-page-context-actions  [pageContextActionsData]="pageContextActions"></app-page-context-actions>
```

State.change.ts
Passing the response of GET API to Page-Context.ts as @Input

```
pageContextActions: any;    
ngOnInit() {
        this.searchService.pageContextActions(this.pirmId).subscribe((res) => {
            this.pageContextActions = res;
        });
```

page-Context.ts
Value is coming as undefined for 1minute

```
@Input() pageContextActionsData;

ngOnInit() {
const value = pageContextActionsData;
 console.log(value) // coming as undefined for 1 mintues after that the data is coming
}
```

Comment: What is the expected and actual behaviour you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [ngif](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) with condition like `pageContextActions` is not `null` or `undefined`.
Once the value assigned in `pageContextActions` , then only it's render the `app-page-context-actions`

```html
<ng-template [ngIf]="pageContextActions">
<app-page-context-actions [pageContextActionsData]="pageContextActions">
</app-page-context-actions>
</ng-template>
```